# DOM table search performance JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a single Page application web site which has been developed in .net and front end is heavily scripted in Jquery. I have introduced a new function in Jquery which requires the process to go thought DOM table, when DOM table hits thousands+ rows it causes a long delays.

```
//The line of code given below causes slow down 
var Linecode = $('#content').children(0).find('tbody tr:Contains(' + partNo +  ') td:nth-child(10)').text(); 
 // complete function given below.
getOriginalPartNoForConsumables: function (partNo, IfAltBtnClicked) {
var Linecode = $('#content').children(0).find('tbody tr:Contains(' + partNo + ') td:nth-child(10)').text();
   for (var x = 0; x < Object.keys(pricing.partsWithPrices).length; x++) {
           var item = pricing.partsWithPrices[x];
               $(item).each(function () {
            if (item["partno"] == partNo && item["linecode"] == Linecode) {
                    partNo = item["partno"] + "*" + item["linecode"];
                }
            })
        }     
    return partNo;
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite this function in a way which can improve the performance of DOM table search.
Please note: This function is called multiple times because values have to be picked up from DOM table every time to achieve the required output and it is not looking into any other areas in DOM hierarchy.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you calling a "DOM table"?  An actual `<table>`?

Comment: When DOM table hits thousands+ rows... you need to rethink your design.    SPA doesn't mean put *everything* on the page at the same time.

Comment: `tr:Contains(' + partNo + ')` will search through the text of all the `td`s .  Is "partNo" mean to be a partial search? or is it an exact match which you can put somewhere more explicit, eg `<tr data-partno='abc123'>` `.find("tr[data-partno=" + partNo + "]")`

Comment: But really, this should be an ajax call and handled on the server to replace the existing rows.  (of course this may need many more changes in your existing app).

Comment: I concur that this should be handled server side with AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, by saying DOM table I mean HTML table which has been populated by a Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, by saying DOM table I mean HTML table which has been populated by an Ajax call. The design was well thought out and it was working well initially however introduction of bad data(not unique) after the development has caused this issue. I have no other option at this stage but to bind the data(lineCode) in HTML table and read it back later no <table><tbody><tr>"<td valign="top" style="border: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197); display: none;">CLA305L</td> " <t/r> </tbody></table>" PartNo has to be the exact match and I can pickup data for linecode in that particular row.